# is there any other way of doing it?

Tags: javascript

The snail climbs 7 feet each day and slips back 2 feet each night, How many days will it take the snail to get out of a well with the given depth? Sample Input 31 Sample Output 6 this is was what i wrote but it didn't work.

My code was

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    var day=0;
    var dist=0;
    
    while(dist<depth-2){
        day++;
        dist=dist+5;
        
    }
    console.log(day)
}
```

is there any other way of doing it

Comment: it is very simple: `(7 - 2)` equals 5, which is the net amount of feet the snail climbs every day. Then `parseInt(31 / 5)` euqals 6, which is the number of days it will take the snail to climb 31 feet.

Comment: btw, I think the premise is wrong. it should take 7 days to climb 31 feet. that's the absolute value, it takes at least a little bit more than 6 days

Comment: @GrafiCode FWIW in 6 days our intrepid snail will have climbed 30’, still well-bound.

Comment: @GrafiCode Your algorithm doesn't work. The snail needs 1 day to climb out a 7 feet well. `parseInt(7 / 5) === 1`. It needs 2 days to climb out a 8 feet well `parseInt(8 / 5) === 1`.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, I noticed that. But OP said "Sample Input 31 Sample Output 6", so I don't know

Comment: @jaba, so that means we need to handle days and nights? I still don't get how it takes 6 days (complete day/night or only days?) to climb 31 feet, as per OP's expectation.

Comment: @GrafiCode The OP doesn’t explicitly state it, but I think they mean to determine if snail escapes the well before nightfall. E.g., snail explicitly slips only at night.

Comment: Yes, there is another way to do it. But I’d recommend continuing to work on it before giving up or letting somebody else do it for you.

Comment: ah ok, so climbing 31 feet takes 6 days and 5 nights...? I will get it eventually :)

Answer (score -1):

The snail climbs 5 feet a day and up to 7 feet the last day. That makes

```
function main() {
  var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
  console.log(Math.max(1, Math.ceil((depth - 2) / 5)));
}
```

Examples:

```js
for (let depth = 1; depth < 32; ++depth) {
  console.log('depth: ' + depth + ', days: ' + Math.max(1, Math.ceil((depth - 2) / 5)));
}
```

Comment: from you logs, it seems that on 1st day it climbs 7 feet and then it climbs 5 feet on subsequent days. could it be expressed as days and nights sequences?

Comment: @GrafiCode I don't understand what this means

Comment: like, `... - depth: 7, day 1 - depth: 6, night 1 - depth 5, night 1 - depth 6, day 2 - depth 7, day 2 - depth 8, day 2 - ...`

Comment: @GrafiCode That doesn't make any sense. The snail won't leave the well in the night. It climbs and the leaves the well during the day. It slips back in the night.

Comment: @GrafiCode I think, I understand your confusion. The log doesn't show the progress. It shows the results for all wells up to 31 feet. The snail leaves a well with 1 foot depth on the first day. It leaves a well with 2 feet depth on the first day, ..., it leaves a well with depth 8 on the second day, ...

Comment: you're right, I see it now subtracting 2 from depth but providing 1 if that's less than 1, thanks for explaining